# Android Studio и Java

Tags: java, android-studio

Привет) Я хорошо знаю Python, а как только поняла, что хочу попробовать сделать своё приложение, решила изучить эту тему. Начала разбираться с Android Studio. Вопрос такой, надо ли вначале скачивать Java, а только потом Android Studio, или он и так работает хорошо??? Просто в одних источниках пишут, что Android Studio не будет работать без него, в других просто скачивают и всё, без всяких Java. Есть ли тут люди знакомые с этим? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Тут есть много людей, знакомых с этим. Что вам мешает скачать, установить и попробовать?

Comment: Дело в том, что я уже вроде как попробовала. Скачала просто Android Studio. Что-то сделала не так, начала искать в чём проблема в интернете и наткнулась на это. Почему-то меня это сильно заинтересовало. А так, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

В Android Studio уже есть встроенный компилятор и сами библиотеки языка.Потребуется скачать эмулятор смартфона и OC Android, если Вы планируете запускать всё на компьютере. Но все будет предложено скачать во время установки Android Studio.

Если нужна какая-то другая версия Java , то в настройках Android Studio можно выбрать нужную версию и он её сам подгрузит.

Answer (score 2):

Аня,

1. Android Studio это средство разработки (IDE), а не язык. Как в питоне есть средство разработки PyCharm - здесь тоже есть средство разработки Android Studio
2. Android - это ОС под которую ведут разработку с использованием Android Studio
3. Android Studio не работает без 2-х важных компонент:

   а) Java - точнее JDK как минимум версии >= 7.0 (рекомендую 8.0)

   б) Android SDK
4. Разработка под Android Studio ведется на 3-х языках программирования: Java, Kotlin и С++. На данный момент рекомендованным языком является Kotlin, но на Java будет больше примеров, документации. На С/С++ ведется разработка критически важных в плане скорости участков.